# Help with adding in LINQ to SQL query

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have an html table that is displaying customer orders. One of these columns is a sub total which needs to add all rows for sub total in the order details table for that specific order. Is there a way to do this within my anonymous type?

Here's some images of what I'm talking about:
[image]

[image]

And the code i'm using minus the total amount addition:

```
var q = db.Orders.Where(x => x.siteUserID == 41)
                      .OrderByDescending(x => x.orderID)
                      .Select(x => new
            {
                dateCreated = x.dateCreated,
                orderID = x.orderID,
                count = x.OrderDetails.Count()
            });
```

Currently I've created a class with identical properties of my LINQ query, and am adding the results to a `List` and within the list calling a function that adds up the sub total.

If it could be done within my original query it would be much cleaner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking for `Sum`

`subtotal = x.OrderDetails.Sum(t=> t.subTotal)`